# Search value in big SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, map

I'm pretty new on apex. I'm writting an apex class to load a csv file and I need to process the data before to insert on a custom object, each record contains account's name but the field has to be the account's id, so I have a big SOQL with id and names of accounts and I need to search on a big list the name to get the id. If I use a for loop I get the cpu time error so I tried to use map to store the data, but  I want the Id and the method get() needs de id to return de value. Is there a way to get the id using the name? or use the name as key in the map and the id as value.
Thanks

Comment: without posting code to show what you tried, you are asking community to do your work for you which is not part of this forum's mission. Keep your code to a minimum and clearly indicate where you are stuck

Comment: not sure what you're doing, but if you use upsert then you can use an externalId to either insert/update your related data or to insert/update the account record itself. just define a text field on the account as external Id and make sure it has the right cross-reference value - here it sounds like you're using the name (I don't recommend this, but if the shoe fits...).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a map from the name to the ID like this (where `names` is the set of names from your CSV; if the number of Accounts is small you won't need that `where` term):

```
Map<String, Id> m = new Map<String, Id>();
for (Account a : [select Id, Name from Account where Name in :names]) {
    m.put(a.Name, a.Id);
}
```

and then when you do a `get` using a name from the CSV the ID will be returned.

Note that this arrangement relies on all Accounts having unique names.

Comment: Yes, the names are uniques. This really work for me. Thanks